# Is it possible to cast one type of bitfield to another type of bitfield with the same total number of bits?

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields, c89

Anyone could tell if its possible to assign one type of bitfield to other type? With support of C90 compiler.

Here is the structs of the bitfields:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned int ERA:2;
    unsigned int destar:2;
    unsigned int srcar:2;
    unsigned int opcode:4;
    unsigned int grp:2;
    unsigned int dumy:3;
} Command;
typedef struct{
    unsigned int cell:15;
} Word;
```

Here is the main program:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    Word word;
    Command cmd;
    cmd.grp = 2;
    word = cmd;
}
```

Let's say I have these 15 bits here:

We arrange them in this order:

Command:

```
Dumy |    grp | opcode |   srcar | destar | ERA
 0 0 0   0 1    0 0 0 1     10      0 0     0 0
```

Word:

```
 |          word              |
000000000000000
```

The goal is that word will be equal to the whole Command (`word = command`)so we'd will look like that:

```
|           word            |
000010001100000
```

Comment: Why is it voted as not clear? It is very clear. The OP is asking whether or not the types of two bitfields are compatible.

Comment: `word = cmd;` is assigned one structure variable to an incompatible variable.  `word.cell = cmd.ERA;` would be assigned one bitfield to another.  There is no casting posted.
`

Comment: But at the end of the story both of them are ints that have taken about 8 bytes... Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Neither takes 8 bytes.  Many reasons to not work: aliment, packing, padding, aliasing.

Comment: Of corse they do! Try Sizeof() and you will see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want here is a union:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        //unsigned int:1;        // padding bit either here...
        unsigned int ERA:2;
        unsigned int destar:2;
        unsigned int srcar:2;
        unsigned int opcode:4;
        unsigned int grp:2;
        unsigned int dumy:3;
        //unsigned int:1;         // ...or here, depending on how you want to read it
    } cmd;
    uint16_t word;
} Cmd;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    Cmd cmd;
    cmd.cmd.grp = 2;
    printf("word=%u\n", cmd.word);
}
```

Comment: Great idea! Thank you! But Yet I'd like to see an answer that will not include union...

Comment: Why would you use padding?

Comment: @DeBanana There are 15 bits specified, so there's one more that the compiler needs to place.  You can use an unnamed bit field as padding to tell the compiler exactly where you expect it.  Given your example, I'm guessing you want it at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Since bitfield layout is compiler dependent, I'm not sure what are you expecting.
The following snippet probably contains undefined behavior, but I guess it's what you are looking for.

```
Word word;
Command cmd;
cmd.grp = 2;

union
{
    Word word;
    Command cmd;
} u;

u.cmd = cmd;
word = u.word;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the bit fields are allocated by the compiler from bit 0 then it is reasonable that both "word" and "cmd" will occupy bits 0:14.

If the bit fields are allocated by the compiler from bit 15 (or maybe bit 31, which is the general situation in most compilers of DSP processors) then both "word" and "cmd" will occupy bits 15:1 (or 31:17 in case of a 32 bits word).

So it seems ok to avoid adding another bit(s) in order to complete the bit field structures to the word size that is allocated by the compiler.

However it is a good habit to do so.

The problem can occur if the "word" of the compiler is a byte. There are micro controllers that their word is a byte. In that case the union definitionmay cause a bug.

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned int ERA:2;
        unsigned int destar:2;
        unsigned int srcar:2;
        unsigned int opcode:4; // When the compiler see that the opcode
                               // bit field is to big to be allocated in the
                               // first byte, The compiler might allocate 
                               // opcode at the first allocation in the
                               // second byte that is allocated to this 
                               // union.
        unsigned int grp:2;
        unsigned int dumy:3;
    } cmd;
    uint16_t word;
} Cmd;
```

In that case the union should be written at this way

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned int ERA:2;
        unsigned int destar:2;
        unsigned int srcar:2;
        unsigned int Spare1:2; 
        unsigned int opcode:4; 
        unsigned int grp:2;
        unsigned int dumy:2; // Assuming that dummy is also a padding
    } cmd;
    uint16_t word;
} Cmd;
```

It is important to notice that the way to catch such bugs is simply by looking at the memory of the processor, at the memory allocation of the variable (or constant) that is declared to be at the type of this union. We should change bit field after bit field and see the impact of the change in the physical memory.